# how could I display normal char?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use **es6 fetch** and get response, but I find that some string display incorrect like `"name":"\\u5b5f\\u6587\\u4e54"`.

how could I fix it?

Comment: Looks like it has been encoded twice...

Comment: @EJTH those are oriental unicode characters.

Comment: Still looks like they have been encoded twice, the double slash hints at that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call JSON.parse on your resulting json string:

```js
var resString = '{"name":"\\u5b5f\\u6587\\u4e54"}';
var res = JSON.parse(resString);

console.log(res);
console.log(res.name);
```

Alternatively, since you are using fetch and retrieving JSON, there's a good chance you maybe be able to just use the `.json()` method on the response object.

Example:

```
yourFetchPromise.then(function(res) {
  return res.json(); // Process result as json here
}).then(function(data) {
  // use data here as a JS object
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vqe5kv1g/1/